# VB6 Binding NULL value to Textbox with ADODB.Recordset

Tags: data-binding, vb6, null, adodb

I'm having to dig into an old VB6 app and I don't have a lot of experience with this language.

Right now I've got a form where the controls are bound to a ADODB.Recordset.  So the "DataField" property of the TextBox is set to "MyIntColumnName".

When the textbox is left empty, I would expect a null to be put into the database, but instead I am getting zeros and a foreign key violation.  Is there any way to specify the binding so that empty == NULL?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the column in the database:  It sounds like it's set to Not Null and a default of 0, which is why, when you don't enter anything, a zero gets submitted.

I don't think changing the binding so that empty==Null will help since you would still get a foreign key violation--your table has a foreign key that depends on a valid value entered.

You're gonna have to either change your table (remove the default and the foreign key)--which may not be the best solution--or change your form field--perhaps to a combo or list value that correlates to the value from the foreign key table.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the field is NULLable and has no default value.  Also, NULL values are no problem on a foreign key field.  Maybe that's not the case on certain databases, but it's certainly OK on MS SQL and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

```
Private Sub txtDataField_Change
Dim cDataField As String
Dim rsTmp as ADODB.Recordset

    If txtDataField.Text = "" And Not txtDataField.DataSource Is Nothing Then
        cDataField = txtDataField.DataField
        txtDataField.DataField = ""
        set rsTmp = txtDataField.DataSource
        rsTmp.Fields(cDataField).Value = Null
        set rsTmp = Nothing
        txtDataField.DataField = cDataField
    End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
YourADODBRecordset.Fields("MyIntColumnname").value = Null
txtTextBox.Datachanged = False
```

Then the recordset will not attempt to update the value from the bound field.